# How select inbox msg by default display on spinner

Tags: java, android, android-spinner

In the system when I select msg that msg by default display on spinner.I require this project those select item display only spinner.If I change item not show previous select item display on spinner.
    **list.java**

```
Spinner sp1;
TextView entry;
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.list);
    sp1=(Spinner) findViewById(R.id.spinner1);
    entry = (TextView)findViewById(R.id.TextView123);
    getFilesnames();        
}
private void getFilesnames() {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    String[] filenames=getApplicationContext().fileList();
    List<String> list=new ArrayList<String>();
    for(int i=0;i<filenames.length;i++){
        list.add(filenames[i]);

    }
    ArrayAdapter<String> filenameAdapter=new ArrayAdapter<String>(this,android.R.layout.simple_spinner_item,list);
    sp1.setAdapter(filenameAdapter);
}
public void onClick(View v) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    String selectFile = String.valueOf(sp1.getSelectedItem());
    openFile(selectFile);
}


private void openFile(String selectFile) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    String value = "";
    FileInputStream fis;

    try {
        fis = openFileInput(selectFile);
        byte[] input = new byte[fis.available()];
        while(fis.read(input) != -1){
            value += new String(input);
        }
        fis.close();
    } catch (FileNotFoundException e) {
        // TODO Auto-generated catch block
        e.printStackTrace();
    } catch (IOException e) {
        // TODO Auto-generated catch block
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
    entry.setText(value);

}
```

Answer (score 0):

Check whether `list` has value after binding like following code:

```
private void getFilesnames() {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    String[] filenames=getApplicationContext().fileList();
    List<String> list=new ArrayList<String>();
    for(int i=0;i<filenames.length;i++){
        list.add(filenames[i]);

    }
    /***
     check here list has value or not
     ***/

    if(list.size() <= 0) {
       list.add("You string.....");
    }

    ArrayAdapter<String> filenameAdapter=new ArrayAdapter<String>(this,android.R.layout.simple_spinner_item,list);
    sp1.setAdapter(filenameAdapter);
}
```

Comment: only selected message display spinner